# how to insert a string in database if value is null

Tags: php, mysqli

In my bind parameters, I am trying to insert answers for each question. I have a simple question which is asking that if a question has no answer, how can I insert the word `No Answer` in its place in the db? This is because at the moment it will not insert any rows are where the answer is NULL. It only does insert if the question has at minimum one answer

Below is attempt:

```
$results = $_POST['value'];
foreach($results as $id => $value) 
{
    $answer = $value;

    $quesid = $question_ids[$id];   

    if($answer = ''){
        $answer = 'No Answer';
    }

    foreach($value as $answer) 
    {
        $insertanswer->bind_param("is", $quesid, $answer);

        $insertanswer->execute();

        if ($insertanswer->errno) {
            // Handle query error here
            echo __LINE__.': '.$insertanswer->error;
            break 7;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a text input then `if($answer == '' || $answer === null){`, if it i from a drop down menu then retrive the value: `if($answer == ''){ //'' is whatever the value is for this option`

Answer (score 1):

its looks like you are using assignment operator (`=`) in if condition i think it should be comparison operator (`==`)

```
if($answer = ''){
        $answer = 'No Answer';
    }
```

should be

```
if($answer == ''){
        $answer = 'No Answer';
    }
```

or

```
if(trim($answer) == '')
```

or

```
if(empty($answer)){
```

also if you want to make sure that `$question_ids[$id]` is int you can use

```
$quesid  = (int)$question_ids[$id];
```

Comment: It seems it still does not insert any records when I have a question with no answers

Comment: should it be `if($empty{$answer))`? tried this but did not work

Comment: sorry its should be `empty($answer)` or `trim($answer) == ''` again pardon i was mistaken it was just an typo

Comment: I should say that `$_POST['value']` comes from here: `var $newBtn = $(("<input class='answerBtnsRow answers' type='button' style='display:%s;' onclick='btnclick(this, " + gQuestionIndex + ");' />").replace('%s', $this.is(':visible') ? 'inline-block' : 'none')).attr('name', "value[" + gQuestionIndex + "][]").attr('value', $this.val()).attr('class', $this.attr('class')).attr('id', $this.attr('id') + 'Row');`. Its a button

Comment: Tried both empty and trim method but still no luck. Kn var dump for `$result` it displays this when there is no answer `NULL array(1) `

Answer (score 1):

Checking if its empty is not enough, you should check for null just incase!

```
//Take notice of === (Identical operator)
    if($answer == '' || $answer === null){
            $answer = 'No Answer';
        }
```